# How to refactor a JavaScript function that is used twice

Tags: javascript, function

I have these two conditions

```
if (civility.labelKey === lady) {
  const contactType = this.contactTypes.find((type) => type.label_key === madam)
  this.onSelect({
    $event: { contactType }
  })
  this.contact.greetings = civility
} else {
  const contactType = this.contactTypes.find((type) => type.label_key === civility.labelKey)
  this.onSelect({
    $event: { contactType }
  })
}
```

I would like to factorize (unify) this code :

```
this.onSelect({
    $event: { contactType }
  })
```

Who repeats twice, do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a function like this:

```
function bindOnSelect(component, contactType){
    component.onSelect({
    $event: { contactType }
  })
}
```

And then call that function:

```
if (civility.labelKey === lady) {
      const contactType = this.contactTypes.find((type) => type.label_key === madam)
      bindOnSelect(this, contactType);
      this.contact.greetings = civility
    } else {
      const contactType = this.contactTypes.find((type) => type.label_key === civility.labelKey)
      bindOnSelect(this, contactType);
    }
```